# Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "titulo" because it is not an "own property" of its parent

Tags: mysql, node.js, express.js, sequelize-js, handlebars.js

Estou tendo um problema com a exibição dos dados do mysql pelo handlebars:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `titulo`, `conteudo`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `postagens` AS `postagens`;
Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "titulo" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.
You can add a runtime option to disable the check or this warning:
See https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access for details
Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "conteudo" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.You can add a runtime option to disable the check or this warning:
See https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access for details
Es
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nas configurações da engine do handlebars, tente utilizar a opção `runtimeOptions` com as propriedades `allowProtoPropertiesByDefault` e `allowProtoMethodsByDefault` com valor `true`.

Ficando dessa forma:

```
    app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({
        defaultLayout: 'main',
        runtimeOptions: {
            allowProtoPropertiesByDefault: true,
            allowProtoMethodsByDefault: true,
        },
    }))
```

Fonte: http://www.prowebguru.com/2020/08/nodejs-express-handlebars-access-denied-resolve-property-solution/#.X595fFDQ9hE

Answer (score 1):

Estava tendo este problema quando estava a fazer as consulta com o mongoose.
Inicialmente a linha de código era :

```js
  Model.find().sort({date:'desc'})
```

Então a adicionei o método lean() do Mongoose, e o problema ficou resolvido com esta linha de código:

```js
  Model.find().lean().sort({date:'desc'})
```

Mais detalhes: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({
        defaultLayout: 'main',
        runtimeOptions: {
            allowProtoPropertiesByDefault: true,
            allowProtoMethodsByDefault: true,
        },
}))
```

AVISO: As pessoas podem travar seu sistema ao fabricar modelos especiais. Não use o código acima.

```js
app.get('/pagamento', function (req, res) {
    Kitten.findAll().then(pagamentos => {
        res.render('pagamento', {
            pagamentos: pagamentos.map(pagamento => pagamento.toJSON())
        })
    })
});
```

Adapte seu código neste exemplo acima.

Comment: muito obrigado!

Comment: Obrigado. sua solução funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score -2):

Pra você que não está conseguindo exibir as postagens, é só inserir a linha: `query:{raw:true}` na criação do database, no arquivo db.js, fica:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('nome_do_banco', 'usuario', 'senha', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    query:{raw:true}
});
```

Outro erro comum que acontece são as pessoas chamarem somente a função `all()`, porém entrou em desuso, agora o correto é `findAll()`:

Substitua o método `Post.All()` por `Post.findAll()` na criação da rota. fica assim:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        Post.findAll().then(function(posts) {
            res.render('home', {posts: posts})
        })
    })
```